# Взаимодействие классов.

Tags: android, listview, java, android-asynctask

У мня имеется два класса.
Основной TApp.class и Read.class(AsyncTask)

В Read.class в фоновом режиме парсится url и в List<String> добавляются Заголовки ссылок.

```
public class Read extends AsyncTask<Boolean, Integer, List<String>> {
    protected List<String> doInBackground(Boolean... status) {
    ...
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> output) {
    ... 
    }
}
```

**Вопрос.** Как мне получить List<String> из Read.class в мой основной(дабы добавить все это дело в ListView).
Или наоборот - как мне добавить все в ListView находясь в классе Read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Некорректная постановка вопроса. Что за основной класс TApp - Activity? В onPostExecute нужно просто обновить ArrayAdapter или какой там у вас адаптер. Если у вас строки добавляются последовательно то можно добавить onProgressChaged и там добавлять строки по одной

**Update**:

используйте MainActivity.this (например) вместо просто this.

Comment: Да, основной класс Activity.
Строка в class Read
listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listitem, output));
Ругается на this

Comment: смотрите апдейт

Comment: Все равно ругается. Классы - разные файлы.

Comment: значит нужно запихнуть асинктаск внутрь активити. Ну зачем вы себе сами жизнь усложняете?

Answer (score 0):

Можно передать ListView в AsyncTask, и в onPostExecute обновить список посредством вызова setAdapter.
Либо же реализовать метод updateBlaBla у Activity, содержащей ListView, передавать активити в асинктаск, и, в onPostExecute вызывать его.

Answer (score 0):

Можно через колбэки сделать
Класс Read

```
public class ReadTask extends AsyncTask<Boolean, Integer, List<String>> {
        public static interface ReadTaskListener{
            void onSuccess(List<String> result);
            void onFailure();
        }

        private final ReadTaskListener listener;

        public ReadTask(ReadTaskListener listener){
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        protected List<String> doInBackground(Boolean... status) {

            return result;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> output) {
            if(listener != null){
                if(error){
                    listener.onFailure();
                } else{
                    listener.onSuccess(output);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Запускать так:

```
new ReadTask(new ReadTask.ReadTaskListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<String> result) {
                //Update adapter
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure() {
                //handle error
            }
        }).execute();
```